# Designing Database Diagrams for Oracle with VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio, oracle

How can I design database diagrams for Oracle with Visual Studio 2010? Or is it only possible for SQL Server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is probably the Oracle Data Access Components (ODAC) with Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio. This is an Oracle created download for integration with Visual Studio.

[ODAC website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/whatsnew/index.html)

I'm not sure if it has everything you will need, but it is a good start.